# How can I convert a python urandom to a string?

Tags: python, string, random, python-3.x, byte

If I call os.urandom(64), I am given 64 random bytes. With reference to [Convert bytes to a Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-byte-array-to-python-string) I tried

```
a = os.urandom(64)
a.decode()
a.decode("utf-8")
```

but got the traceback error stating that the bytes are not in utf-8.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 0: invalid start byte
```

with the bytes

```
b'\x8bz\xaf$\xb6\x93q\xef\x94\x99$\x8c\x1eO\xeb\xed\x03O\xc6L%\xe70\xf9\xd8
\xa4\xac\x01\xe1\xb5\x0bM#\x19\xea+\x81\xdc\xcb\xed7O\xec\xf5\\}\x029\x122
\x8b\xbd\xa9\xca\xb2\x88\r+\x88\xf0\xeaE\x9c'
```

Is there a fullproof method to decode these bytes into some string representation? I am generating sudo random tokens to keep track of related documents across multiple database engines.

Comment: Odd way of doing it... Why not just have a more "central" db that generates its own ID, which refers to the other IDs...? Or, instead of using `urandom` - why not use a uuid4 or similar?

Comment: Can this be also used to generate a random seed?

Comment: Django's generate random string logic. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/crypto.py#L51

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The code below will work on both Python 2.7 and 3:

```
from base64 import b64encode
from os import urandom

random_bytes = urandom(64)
token = b64encode(random_bytes).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: you don't need to decode it only b64encode is enough. 

>>> rstring = os.urandom(16)
>>> rstring
b'\xaf\xec)Uf\x1fb\x8dQ\xfa\xc0\x95\x9c\xd1T\x97'
>>> b64encode(rstring)
b'r+wpVWYfYo1R+sCVnNFUlw=='
>>> b64encode(rstring).decode('utf-8')
'r+wpVWYfYo1R+sCVnNFUlw=='

Answer (score 14):

You have random bytes; I'd be very surprised if that ever was decodable to a string.

If you **have** to have a unicode string, decode from Latin-1:

```
a.decode('latin1')
```

because it maps bytes one-on-one to corresponding Unicode code points.

Comment: Seems to work every time. I just need a string which django char field will accept.

Comment: Yeah; it is a pity Django only added a binary field in the upcoming 1.6 release.

Answer (score 10):

You can use base-64 encoding. In this case:

```
a = os.urandom(64)
a.encode('base-64')
```

Also note that I'm using `encode` here rather than `decode`, as `decode` is trying to take it from whatever format you specify into unicode. So in your example, you're treating the random bytes as if they form a valid `utf-8` string, which is rarely going to be the case with random bytes.

Comment: I am given an error stating that 'bytes' object has not attribute encode. Is this code specific with some version of python? I am using 3.3

Comment: I'm not sure about python3.x. I'm using python2.7

Comment: @user1876508 have you tried using `str(b'hello', encoding)`? It might work with 'base-64' as your encoding.

Comment: str(os.urandom(64),'base-64') gives me LookupError: unknown encoding: base-64

Comment: i am getting error bytes object has no attribute encode.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you need 64 bytes represented as string?

Maybe what you really need is N-bits token?
If so, use [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html). The secrets module provides functions for generating secure tokens, suitable for applications such as password resets, hard-to-guess URLs, and similar.

```
import secrets

>>> secrets.token_bytes(16)  
b'\xebr\x17D*t\xae\xd4\xe3S\xb6\xe2\xebP1\x8b'

>>> secrets.token_hex(16)  
'f9bf78b9a18ce6d46a0cd2b0b86df9da'

>>> secrets.token_urlsafe(16)  
'Drmhze6EPcv0fN_81Bj-nA'
```

Or Maybe you need 64 chars length random string? import string

```
import secrets
alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
password = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(64))
```

Answer (score 2):

this easy way:

```
a = str(os.urandom(64))
print(F"the: {a}")
print(type(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying to encode / decode using the codec using `urandom(16)` I would get a `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 0: invalid continuation byte`

This is what I ended up doing.

```py
import os
import binascii

a = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(32)).decode()
print(a)

'fd78f19c8bdcd7bc086d5a34b8d0ebccbd501fd2eea18e46699bb52efa48ac3c'
```