# python generate fixed size (16 bytes) real random string

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, byte

I want to generate a 16 bytes long random string for encryption purpose (AES encryption) in python3. `urandom(n)` seems to be the way to go to get real random characters:

> os.urandom(n):
>
> Return a string of n random bytes suitable for
>   cryptographic use.

As I need a 16 bytes random string, I thought this would do the job for me: **EDIT** I included now a more complex example, demonstrating the issues I have.

```
from os import urandom
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from base64 import b64encode
import sys

rnd=urandom(16)
rnd_bytes=b64encode(rnd).decode('utf-8')

print(sys.getsizeof(rnd_bytes))
print(len(rnd_bytes))
print(type(rnd_bytes))

AESencrypter=AES.new('my key',AES.MODE_CBC,rnd_bytes)
```

Note: I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21927326/4673476) for converting the urandom *byte* to a *string*. The output is:

> 73
>
> 24
>
> File
>   "/User/test.py", line 14, in 
>       AESencrypter=AES.new('my kes',AES.MODE_CBC,rnd_bytes)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py",
>   line 95, in new
>       return AESCipher(key, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py",
>   line 59, in **init**
>       blockalgo.BlockAlgo.**init**(self, _AES, key, *args, **kwargs)   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py",
>   line 141, in **init**
>       self._cipher = factory.new(key, *args, **kwargs) ValueError: IV must be 16 bytes long

As you see, the length is not 16 (probably because of the conversion between byte and string). How can I fix that?

Comment: That’s not telling you the length of the object...

Comment: `getsizeof` doesn't give you the exact size of the value that your object holds it returns the size of the whole object include all the attributes, namespace, etc.

Comment: What should I use instead? If I use `rnd_bytes` for crypto functions that expect 16 bytes long input, I receive an error: "ValueError: Value must be 16 bytes long"

Comment: Then could you give a [mcve] of that?

Comment: Use `len` instead.

Comment: Have you tried just `AES.new('my key',AES.MODE_CBC,urandom(16))`?

Comment: Why did you use`b64encode`? `urandom` should give you exactly what you need.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you get back from `urandom()` is the length you asked for:

```
>>> rnd = os.urandom(16)
>>> rnd
b'\xf0\xe9ZG3\xf0(\xd2\xc3\x04/\xf1\xae\x0b-\xb4'
>>> len(rnd)
16
```

So use that as is.

If you encode it in base-64 it won't be 16 bytes anymore. That is because base-64 (1) pads out your data to a multiple of 3 bytes, making it 18 long, and then (2) encodes each group of 3 bytes as 4 bytes (so that they will all be printable characters), which makes it longer still. That explains the length of 24 that you report.

Do not use `sys.getsizeof()` to discover the length of your data. That returns the size of Python's internal data structure.