# Python3: Trying to decode b' ' string to ascii

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, cryptography

I'm trying to decrypt a OTP. The key is generated with the following code:

```
class OTPGenerator(metaclass=Singleton):
_OTP_LEN = 128

def __init__(self):
    self.otp = os.urandom(OTPGenerator._OTP_LEN)

def get_otp(self):
    return self.otp
```

I get receive the encrypted text thru a socket connection:

```
b'7Vf\xba\xe1\xb1.\xeb\x05Y\xccL 1\xb2\xec\xb1<0\xb36\xce\xc3\x02\xd6^\xc6z\x15_\x88\x14k\xe9\x8c\xb1\xa5{\xd5\xe3LKE8\x16\xe2\xe1\xf0\xe1+[_\xd47\x13\xd8T\xa7E\x8f\xf3SR\xd1'
```

And another encrypted text given by be as plaintext:

```
input = flag
Encrypted Input: b'\t\x17J\x9c'
```

I'm trying to decode them before XOR-ing them, but they are casted as strings.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue before?

Comment: Post text as *text*, please also show what research you've done into solving this yourself.

Comment: If it is a `str` you can't decode it. If it is `bytes` you can. Share the code

Comment: `\xbe` is an invalid start byte for utf-8 anyway, so more investigation into the source of that data might be needed.

Comment: Try printing your text without the decode part, you text seem to be decoded already.

Answer (score 0):

The `os.urandom` module produces N random bytes with N being passed as argument. In that sense, I'm not sure what you want to decode since this is random data.

In any way, there is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21927326/11501135) that might be what you are looking for, which converts the data produce by `os.urandom` into a base64 encoded string.

```
from base64 import b64encode
from os import urandom

random_bytes = urandom(64)
token = b64encode(random_bytes).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Already found this answer, unfortunately it's not helpful as urandom() output is bytes, but receiving it thru a socket connection interprets it as a string.

Comment: @adicpnn: *but receiving it thru a socket connection interprets it as a string...* it does not.